# is there any GDIFF tool for windows

Tags: encoding, delta

i have Bsdiff and Bspatch tool with me which works on windows through command prompt but i need to know the compression difference between the GDIFF and BSDIFF therefore is there any tool for GDIFF similar to bsdiff which works on windows?

Answer (score 0):

I heard that nobody is answering your question, so I am here.

Did you ever try "meld" or "Beyond Compare"?  These are the best I have tried before.  The only problem is they both cannot print, but they give the best comparison results.  Also, they compare files and folders, as well as 3-way merging.

May be you can say more about your requirement?

Comment: actually im trying to point out the difference between GDIFF and BSDIFF encoding methods . i have a bsdiff tool for windows which generates patch  for any executable files but for GDIFF i did not have any kind of tool to display the patch size for the purpose of comparision